# STP hello timer

Tags: networking, timer, spanning-tree, stp

In STP we have the MAX age timer. It tells us how long to wait for a superior BPDU (On root or blocking ports) before it assumes the Root bridge or the link is dead. Giving that timer, why does every bridge must know the Hello timer as well? How do they benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

According to 802.1D, Hello Time is the interval between periodic transmissions of Configuration Messages by Designated Ports. Using the timer makes bridge sure that at least one BPDU is transmitted by a Designated Port in each HelloTime period.

Check the [standart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1D).